# Google script for custom concatenation of values in a range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

I was trying to solve the problem alone for a two days, and finally come here.

I need to write a custom function in google script which will be concatenating the range's values with some filter(i.e. skip blank cells or cells with value equal to "-").

formula in google sheets should looks like:

```
=concat_costum(A3:N3,"-")
```

result should looks like:

```
trpd-hex-phex-crfl-wi-ins-td-max_op_temp
```

I wrote the next code:

```html
function concat_costum(pRange,s){
  var out=""
  for(i=0;i<pRange.length;++i){
    var currentValue = pRange[i]
    if (!(currentValue == "-" || currentValue == "" || currentValue == "undefined")) {
      out = out+currentValue+s
    }
    
  }
  return out.slice(0,-1)
}
```

but the its output is:

```
trpd,hex,phex,crfl,,-,wi,ins,td,max_op_temp,,,,
```

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Faster formula**

Custom functions can take awhile to load sometimes, and your problem is simple enough to use a much faster spreadsheet formula:

```
=join("-", filter(A1:A6, A1:A6 <> ""))
```

**Custom function**

You can also do it as a custom function by utilizing some of JavaScript's built in array functions:

```
function concat_custom(s, array) {
    array = conformToOneDimensionalArray(array);

    return array.filter(function (value) {
      return value != "";
    }).join("-");
}

function conformToOneDimensionalArray(value) {
  if (!Array.isArray(value)) {
    value = [value];
  }
  else if (Array.isArray(value[0])) {
    value = value.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a.concat(b);
    });
  }

  return value;
}
```

But you need to make sure that the paramter `array` is a one-dimensional array. A spreadsheet range will either be passed as a single value, a two-dimensional array.